# Connecting to legacy database from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

I am trying to create a gem to provide models for a legacy database but my gem can't see the app's configuration:

In my database.yml:

```
firefly:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: ...
  username: ...
  password: ...
```

model, in the gem:

```
module FireflyRails
  class User < ActiveRecord::base
    establish_connection :firefly
    set_table_name "fly_users"

  end
end
```

I prototyped this in a regular rails app, and was able to read from the database without issue. However, when used from the gem, I can't even start the console:

Abbreviated backtrace:

```
/Users/Jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@lunar/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in **`resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)**
    from /Users/Jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@lunar/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /Users/Jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@lunar/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
    from /Users/Jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@lunar/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
```

The examples I've found around the web all seem to use the standard rails database, I can't find an example of a gem using a different database configuration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you end up going with something here?  I am trying to sort out the same issue.

Comment: No. If you find a solution, I'd love to know.